# Load template or view depending upon a $_GET variables content

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I am designing a Q & A website use php. Here is the directory structure:

```
+include
  db.php
  user.php
  template.php
  ...
  question.php
+public
  +images
  +styles
.htaccess
index.php
...
```

I want to use `index.php` 's REQUEST_STRING to load a template.

For example: `index.php?page=signin` will load the function `get_signin_template()` in `template.php`. And will show the visitor a URL like `http://example.com/signin/`.

Here are my questions:

1. How to load different templates in `index.php` (what should do in this file)?
2. How to rewrite the url (using apache mod_rewrite)?

Comment: You should look at Codeigniter and how they accomplish this

Comment: No PHP function can show an URL. It's browser requesting URLs, not PHP "showing" them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Answer to Question 1

```
$valid_templates = array('signin', 'logout', 'home');
if(isset($_GET['page'])
   and in_array($_GET['page'], $valid_templates)) {
    $function_name = 'get_' . $_GET['page'] . '_template';
    $template = call_user_func($function_name);
}
```

See [`call_user_func()` in the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.call-user-func.php) and the [`in_array()` function in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php).

I think it is also worth mentioning that I would not do it this way myself. Mapping URLs directly to functions is an inflexible way of doing things.

The reason I have added the `$valid_templates` array is to ensure the user doesn't attempt to change the URL in an attempt to call a nonexistant function etc. You would need to add each page/template function to it.

If you really like this way of working then I would recommend you check out [Limonade](http://www.limonade-php.net/) as it uses a similar dispatch method as the one you are attempting to setup (the following example is from [their official site](http://www.limonade-php.net/)):

```
require_once 'vendors/limonade.php';
dispatch('/', 'hello');
  function hello()
  {
      return 'Hello world!';
  }
run();
```

But is a little safer and easier to manage in my opinion. Plus all the "hard" plumbing work has been done and you can just focus on adding your pages.

Another similar option is [Slim](http://www.slimframework.com/), which looks like this:

```
require 'Slim/Slim.php';
Slim::init();
Slim::get('/hello/:name', function ($name) {
    echo "Hello $name";
});
Slim::run();
```

Example from [their site](http://www.slimframework.com/).

### Answer to Question 2

Something along these lines in your .htaccess file should work for your rewriting needs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: You beat me to it. And in addition, URL rewriting. Hopefully you are using Apache? Then use htaccess.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I entirely concur. @Cogicero good point. I had assumed the rewrite process was in place!

Comment: You tell me the PHP framework of **Limonade** and **Slim**, and @RobertPitt tell me **codeigniter**. Which framework is more easy and simple for new users?

Comment: @MYBot I have never used Codeignitor, but I have used Slim and Limonade. Codeignitor is an old framework written for PHP4 and it is much larger than either Limonade or Slim. If you are running PHP 5.3 then I would choose Slim and otherwise Limonade.

Comment: @Treffynon: Errr Codeigniter? Not at all. It's not old, and it's not for PHP 4 only :) Currently, Codeigniter Reactor (2.0) is in very active development. http://www.codeigniter.com

Comment: @Cogicero I see. I wasn't aware of V2s release in January. I will have to reassess it.

Answer (score -2):

1.for index.php?page=signin

```
$urlEnd=$_GET['page'];
require('path_to_file'.$urlEnd);//Require your file
header('Location: index.php?/$urlEnd');//WARNING!!! HEADER MUST go befor any echo's
```

Comment: This is **wide** open to abuse from users who want to attempt to load in files anywhere on your server. It is a gaping security hole.

Comment: what's the use of including a file here?